# special comment cannot match lexer rule

Tags: antlr

One example text I like to parse is like this -

```
@comment {
    { something }
    { something else }
}
```

Basically "@comment" is the key to search, after that is a pair of matching braces. I do not need to parse what is between the braces. Since this is similar to C' multi-line comment, I have my grammar based on that:

```
grammar tryit;


tryit : top_cmd 
        ;

WS : ('\t' | ' ')+  {$channel = HIDDEN;};

New_Line : ('\r' | '\n')+   {$channel = HIDDEN;};

top_cmd :cmds 
        ;

cmds
    : cmd+
    ;

cmd
    : Comment
    ;

Comment
    : AtComment    Open_Brace  ( options {greedy = false; }: . )+  Close_Brace
    ;

AtComment
    : '@comment'
    ;

Open_Brace
    : '{'
    ;

Close_Brace
    : '}'
    ;
```

But in testing in ANTLRWORKS, I get a EarlyExitException immediately.

Do you see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that I see:

1. you didn't account for the spaces between `"@comment"` and the first `"{"`. Note that the spaces are put on the HIDDEN channel for parser rules, ***not*** for lexer rules!
2. with `( options {greedy = false; }: . )+` you're just matching the first `"}"`, not balanced braces.

Try something like this instead:

```
tryit
 : top_cmd 
 ;

top_cmd
 : cmds 
 ;

cmds
 : cmd+
 ;

cmd
 : Comment
 ;

Comment
 : '@comment' ('\t' | ' ')* BalancedBraces
 ;

WS
 : ('\t' | ' ')+  {$channel = HIDDEN;}
 ;

New_Line
 : ('\r' | '\n')+   {$channel = HIDDEN;}
 ;

fragment
BalancedBraces
 : '{' (~('{' | '}') | BalancedBraces)* '}'
 ;
```